# Replacement for (mkl) pardiso for arm64 (Apple Silicon)

Tags: solver, arm64, pardiso

For an academic numerical project we use as direct solvers mostly pardiso (from mkl) and cholmod. Now I switch to Apple Silicon (amazing fast, a quarter of the build time!) and cannot use Intel's mkl for native compiling any more.

- For BLAS openblas runs fine
- For positive definite systems cholmod
  works fine
- For non positive definite systems (where pardiso is great), I'm searching for a replacement
- By 01.2022 there is no academic Pardiso available any more.

Answer (score 1):

One could use Apple's Accelerate Framework instead of openBLAS. SuiteSparse finds it by default.

For non-positive definite systems, one can use umfpack from SuiteSparse. However it is (in my experience) slow compared to cholmod.

Comment: This is the solution I finally choose and I can confirm all statements. 
For me Apple's Accelerate Framework fails with arpack for complex eigenvalue problems but it is very fast for cholmod (in the GPL build).